# Running Scala Spark applications on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, scala, apache-spark

I've installed Spark and Scala using Homebrew. I can run the Spark-shell. I also installed Spark-IDE by placing it in `usr/local/share` (not sure this is the right way to do it) and put a symbolic link to it in the Applications folder. Now I want to run Spark applications written in Scala inside Eclipse; how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The common way how to create and run Apache Spark job is to:

1, create package - usually **jar file** - you can package it with maven for example.

2, spark-submit to start and submit job

- there are few ways how (or correctly where) should your spark jobs run - its usually defined by master
- so, when you have jar package with you job you can go to spark folder/bin - there is `spark-submit`

`./bin/spark-submit  --class MainClass.class  --master local[2]  <application-jar>`, where

`<application-jar>` is your spark job package as jar file

`MainClass.class` entrypoint for job

`master` - apache spark jobs are usually submitted to cluster, but for testing purposes you can use local as a master. Number here defines number of threads for job execution.

- If you want to start spark application inside eclipse (for example as a tests ) you simply create SparkContext programmatically - set local as a master using SparkConf and run (I think spark will need `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable - in that case just download hadoop and set `$HADOOP_HOME`)

Comment: How do I make Eclipse see the Spark libraries? How do I import the Spark libraries into the application?

Comment: @jkabrg Eclipse is just IDE, It depends how you include your dependencies to project - eg. u can use maven or some similar tool.

Comment: I'm interested in step 1, I think.

Comment: @jkabrg check [this link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html#wordcount__section_iz2_vbb_h5) how to setup maven for scala and [Scala SparkPi example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala)